# Extending Apple Airport Extreme Network

Tags: macos, network

I'm trying to add a second router(a Netgear R7000) to extend my current network which uses a 5th generation Airport Extreme as the base. I am trying to set it up such that there is one continuous network with a single password.

Right now it exists as three separate networks (Airport, Netgear and Netgear5G). I tried to set it up as an ethernet connected roaming network. The problem I have is the configuration pages shown on the Apple site ([Wi-Fi base stations: Setting up and configuring a roaming network (802.11 a/b/g/n)](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204616)) showing connection sharing options does not seem to be found anywhere on my current Airport utilities software.

Does anyone know where these configuration pages can be found or how I can configure the routers into a single network?

Comment: When my late model Airport extreme died, I went with a Netgear R7000 2.4 ghz and 5ghz router. Give the two freqs the same name and password and you get a single network. Range is superior to Airport, so you may not need it.

Comment: You need to configure the Netgear to be an *access point*; turn off all router functionality and set the SSID/passphrase the same as your Airport.  For the price, you would do better to go with a dedicated AP like [Ubiquiti](https://amzn.to/2CEPLf0)